# Kdiff3 works very slowly in 16.04

Tags: diff

After installing 16.04 I've noticed that Kdiff3 worked much slower than in 14.04. In 14.04 it worked well with 200MB files and in 16.04 even 2MB files take around 1-2 minutes to process. And 200MB file is impossible to wait until it is opened.

Is there anything can be done to make it work faster? Or may the there is another GUI tool capable of processing large files without consuming too much memory and relatively fast? I've tried Meld on 200MB file but it instantly consumed around 6GB of memory and system almost freezed (had to kill it). Kdiff3 does not consume so much memory.

Comment: The same problem for me on 18.04. On 14.04 it was perfect. I think we have to find out first if kdiff3 version difference gives this regression or the OS version difference.